# Delayed job not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, delayed-job, web-worker

I want to scrape some website & I want that this should be done by separate worker process. I came to know about delayed job to do jobs in background. I am using [collectiveidea / delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) in my rails application.I followed the installation steps for rails 3.0 & active record.

After that I created a dj.rb in lib file & wrote code as follows.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
class Dj_testing
  def perform
    #code for scraping the site
    #code to add entry into database 
  end
end
```

Now after that I use following command to start worker

> script/delayed_job start
>
> rake jobs:work

My worker started & on my terminal I can see

> [Worker(host:user1234-desktop pid:9487)] Starting job worker

Now my problem is When I call the perform method directly It works fine. I mean following code works perfectly scrapes the site and populates the database.

> ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Dj_testing.new.perform

But when I delay that same job it adds job to delayed_job table & does nothing :(

> ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Dj_testing.delay.new

or

> ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Delayed::Job.enqueue Dj_testing.new

```
 #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 150, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: 
"---!ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod \nargs: ...", last_error: nil,
run_at: "2012-04-27 05:25:29", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil,
queue: nil,created_at:     "2012-04-27 05:25:29", updated_at: "2012-04-27 05:25:29">
```

Why the job is not working as desired?

Comment: Could you try renaming the file to match the class name? dj.rb having class Dj_testing can sometimes cause inconsistencies. Try naming the class DjTesting and call the file dj_testing.rb.

Comment: yes that was the reason.. File name & class name should be same..

Answer (score 0):

You need to call 'delay' on the object on which you are invoking the method. So, in your case, it should be:

```
Dj_testing.new.delay.perform
```

and not

```
Dj_testing.delay.new
```

Answer (score 0):

@salil's way of calling the method is correct, however you might be suffering from other issues.

Follow the guidelines in my answer to this post (I did not post here since there are many :-))
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15000180/226255

I hope this helps